# xpath expression building

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following Html element and I would like to extract the value "9-0036031069" from the attribute "data-sku". How can I do this using xpath ?

```
<li data-selectionkey="4004|240|" data-sku="9-0036031069" class="ws-variation-list-item kor-swatch-selected" data-variation-value="4004" data-selected="true" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: This is an extremely basic question. Have you actually tried it yourself first? Or, asked differently, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: HTML is not XML, unless it's valid XHTML. If it's not, then XPath isn't going to help you, it can only operate on well-formed XML documents.

Comment: Well, the problem is that there are multiple html elements with `data-sku' attribute in the document and only one of them contains the `data-selected` attribute.

Comment: That's very relevant to your question. I suggest editing to reflect this, but this is still irrelevant if your HTML is not XHTML.

Comment: How do you expect us to know what uniquely identifies this attribute, if you do not show the document? Please show the complete HTML.

Comment: @user2325154 Getting `data-sku` attribute from `<li>` having `data-selected` attribute equals `true` : `//li[@data-selected='true']/@data-sku`. Is that what you're looking for?